# Easiest way to display a matplotlib graph based on input on a website?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I currently have code where there is an user input and then data visualization (matplotlib) that pops up based on their input. However, I don't want the user to go through the code and run it themselves, rather I would like some sort of interface where the code is in the background. Is there any easy way to do this? It doesn't have to be pretty.

I am using a pandas DF and matplotlib.

Comment: [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) can be used to create an executable. This way the user does not need to have python installed to run the executable.

Comment: You can try a Jupyter notebook with [Voilà](https://blog.jupyter.org/and-voil%C3%A0-f6a2c08a4a93) that hides the code but lets users change prespecified inputs and see the results